# Why angularjs filter is not working with track?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Cant we use filter with track in angularjs? if we can what is the issue behind this. please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Tc34P/34/

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<p ng-init='dd=[{"a":["abcd"]},{"n":["efrg","efgh"]},{"z":["zela"]},{"p":["mithun","mithun","mithun"]}]'></p>
<input type="text" ng-model="x">
 <div ng-repeat="cc in dd">
<div ng-repeat="(v,s) in cc ">
    {{v}}
  <div ng-repeat ="c in s track by $index | filter:x">
     {{c}}
    </div>
 <div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put the `track by` expression last:

```
ng-repeat="c in s | filter:x track by $index"
```